# htaccess block request with id as parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need a little help on htaccess file.
I want to remove port from my domain but this blocked requests that have id on the url.

For example:

- /content-manager/collection-types/application::posts.posts (WORKS)
- /content-manager/collection-types/application::posts.posts/83  (ERROR 404)

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:32000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:32000/$1 [P,L]
```

Please can somebody help me fix htaccess file?

Comment: Does `http://127.0.0.1:32000/content-manager/collection-types/application::posts.posts/83` work from a browser?

Comment: @anubhava no it doesn't work

Comment: In that case issue is with the site running on `32000` not with these rules

Comment: I am using strapi CMS and in localhost with wampserver it works perfectly. When I deploy online, I can create for example a post, but I cant delete or edit it.